# How flag text that is a lat/long so that recognised as a location when sent as an email

Tags: ios, location, text-recognition

I allow my users to share messages and to share them with others in different ways. Eg. FB or Email...

If the text contains a lat/long, and the user shares this message, I want it to be recognised by FB, Email... as a location so that the receiver of the message can just tap on the text and be taken to their map app.

Is this possible ?

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. How about we turn to one specific case. What API calls are you using, what is your exact input? What exactly do you expect to happen? First hint: For email it's up to the email client to parse potential geo info and then link it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create links for apple map or google maps

For apple map you can use url like below, make it as a hyperlink and share

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=lat,long
```